# With Whom or Where Can I Play D&D

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons

I’m new to D&D and want to play with someone if anyone could introduce me to the game and invite me to your online table (is that what you call where you play D&D) I would be very greatful

Comment: Ultimately, though, this isn’t really the place to find games to join, including basic, intro games where people can teach you how to play. Those totally exist, just not here. Please see the [Tour] for more about our site—we’d love to help you, but we specialize in answering specific questions, not hosting full introductions.

Comment: thanks, can you recommend one of those “intro games” if you can

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot; I don’t know of any at the moment. We do have a [list of recommended discussion forums](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/4563), many of which may either host games or at least host advertisements for games people want to run. [Roll20.net](https://roll20.net/) might also be a good place to look for them—a lot of people use their service to run and play D&D, so maybe some of them are doing a new-player-friendly game. (Note that these suggestions—and more—can be found in that first link under “This question already has answers here:” in the blue box above.)